# How to access WAMP Server form everywhere?

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I just created my first homepage in the last weeks and now I want it to show it to my friends.
I am using WAMPSERVER 2.5 and followed A LOT of guides but nothing really worked for me.

First of all I am new to this, I have no idea how all this accessing works exactly. I guess I point out how I understand that it should work.

On my PC where I wrote my htmls css php and so on I can access via

localhost:8080/foldername/homepage.php

Okay I changed the port from 80 to 8080 cause a lot of guides recommenced it.

A few days ago I was able to reach this with my local IP

192.168.2.103/foldername/homepage.php

or something like this

I have no Idea how I did that and at the moment it doesn't work anymore.

My httpd.config file is also pretty messed up (and too long to post here), maybe I should reinstall WAMP.

Okay to come back to my question: If I set up everything correctly will I be able to access my homepage on my PC via

http://IPv4-address/homepage.php
like http://91.11.87.45/homepage.php

without buying a domain and only having WAMP installed? The page is intended not to be online 24/7 only when I and my friends need it, or WAMP is always online when my PC is powered.

I already did 
- "Put Online"
- portforwarding on router and firewall
- turned off firewall/antivir
- changed httpd.conf and httpd-vhost.conf accordingly to the guides I read
- tried every combination of ips and ports to access homepage.php

and now I am out of Ideas. But I guess I'm not the only one with problems, because all those guides comments where full of questions and problems^^

I hope I explained the problem well enough :P

Comment: Are you sure that your router is not sitting behind another router, this happens sometimes in apartment blocks or compounds. If thats the case you are never going to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

When you access it from inside the same network, you would still need the 8080:

192.168.2.103:8080/foldername/homepage.php

But if you are outside the network, it would depend on how your port is forwarded. If you have port 8080 forwarded to 192.168.2.103 port 8080, then you would need:

http://91.11.87.45:8080/***foldername***/homepage.php (also folder name would still be same as if it were localhost)

If on your router you have port 80 forwarded to 192.168.2.103 port 8080, then

http://91.11.87.45/***foldername***/homepage.php

should work, but some routers are funny and can only do the in port as the same as outport, just to a specific internal address.

so if you can do:

- localhost:8080/foldername/homepage.php

and can also do:

- 192.168.2.103:8080/foldername/homepage.php

but CAN'T do:

-http://91.11.87.45:8080/foldername/homepage.php

OR

-http://91.11.87.45/foldername/homepage.php

then the trouble is in the port forwarding of the router.

If you CAN'T do:

- 192.168.2.103:8080/foldername/homepage.php

Then sounds like something in WAMP config

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer! Okay 192.168.2.103:8080/foldername/homepage.php works, http ://ip:8080/foldername/homepage.php not. So the problem is somewhere with my router/firewall? After I figured out how to post screenshot I will take some of my portforwarding

Comment: http://imgur.com/JwFMRUC


Okay this is my current router portforwarding where HarcoreHolly is my PC with 192.168.2.103

The Text says "Redirect or forward public port to client port on device"

I did the same stuff for UDP and all this again in my firewall settings.